# List Product Tags in Category Specific

Tags: tags

I want to show the product tag on the product category page. I have the code, but it only shows it as a dropdown menu. I want to show as list

with link for each tags. Please help me! That’s my code :

```
<?php
$term = get_queried_object();
$product_category = $term->slug;
//Iterate through all products in this category
$query_args = array(
'product_cat' => $product_category,
'post_type' => 'product',
//Grabs ALL post
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
$term_array = array();
while( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
$term_array[] = $term->name;
}
}
}
//Remove any duplicates.
$tags_unique = array_unique($term_array);
//Sort alphabetically
asort($tags_unique);
//Output
echo ''; echo 'Filter by Tag'; foreach($tags_unique as $unique) { //it's faster to "guess" the tag slug by replacing spaces with dashes and stripping special chars $special_characters = array("=", "+", "/", "'",")","("); $tag_slug = str_replace(" ","-",$unique); $tag_slug = strtolower(str_replace($special_characters,"",$tag_slug)); echo ' '. $unique . ''; } echo '';
//Reset the query
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```